# View references materialized for simple MySQL VIEWs?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

Original question: If I have a view: `CREATE VIEW foo AS SELECT * FROM bar WHERE bar.deleted = 0` are there any queries which perform slower ie. `SELECT ... FROM bar ... WHERE bar.deleted = 0 AND ...` vs `SELECT ... FROM foo`. In yet another way, is it always just a simple query rewrite?

This is a generic question and I do not have a specific table to show because I am trying to help with designing a framework.

Edit: the [MySQL handbook](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subquery-optimization.html) has this under 9.2.1.18.3:

> As of MySQL 5.7.6, the optimizer handles derived tables and view references the same way: It avoids unnecessary materialization whenever possible, which enables pushing down conditions from the outer query to derived tables and produces more efficient execution plans. Before MySQL 5.7.6, derived tables were always materialized, whereas equivalent view references were sometimes materialized and sometimes merged. This inconsistent treatment of equivalent queries could lead to performance problems: Unnecessary derived table materialization takes time and prevents the optimizer from pushing down conditions to derived tables.

Does anyone have examples where view references were sometimes materialized with the simple VIEW definition I've given (all fields select from a single table with a constant filter on a single integer field)? Or that only happened with more complex VIEW definitions? That is exactly what I am after.

Comment: Are those indexes used by this query? Usually it would require `deleted` column to be first in the index. Please post output of `EXPLAIN` for this query

Comment: I rewrote the question to be more clear.

Comment: Regression between what version and what version?

Comment: Still not clear enough.  Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW CREATE VIEW` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: Amended the question with an almost adequate quote from the MySQL handbook. All it needs is an example.

Comment: I suspect that an example would cover only one case, and not be generic.  Your best bet is to avoid `VIEWs` wherever practical.  5.7.6 improved optimizations of views, but I suspect there are still cases where manually folding in the view gives better optimization.  (And, no, I do not have an example.)